# How to modify ease out bounce equation for C# XNA?

Tags: c#, animation, xna-4.0, graphics2d

I found Robert Penner's easing functions on the web. They work awesome. I got my hands on a bounce one, and it also works well, but I want to make the first bounce either less or eliminate it altogether. How?

```
public static float EaseOutBounce(float currentTime, float startValue, float changeInValue, float totalTime)
{
    float magic1 = 7.5625f;
    float magic2 = 2.75f;
    float magic3 = 1.5f;
    float magic4 = 2.25f;
    float magic5 = 2.625f;
    float magic6 = 0.75f;
    float magic7 = 0.9375f;
    float magic8 = 0.984375f;

    if ((currentTime /= totalTime) < (1 / magic2)) //0.36%
    {
        return changeInValue * (magic1 * currentTime * currentTime) + startValue;
    }
    else if (currentTime < (2 / magic2)) //0.72%
    {
        return changeInValue * (magic1 * (currentTime -= (magic3 / magic2)) * currentTime + magic6) + startValue;
    }
    else if (currentTime < (2.5 / magic2)) //0.91%
    {
        return changeInValue * (magic1 * (currentTime -= (magic4 / magic2)) * currentTime + magic7) + startValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return changeInValue * (magic1 * (currentTime -= (magic5 / magic2)) * currentTime + magic8) + startValue;
    }
}
```

I have skimmed Robert's pdf (77 pages) and I have played around with the values to see their effect, but I have only succeeded in breaking it. :-)  The first bounce appears to be in the second if statement.  I changed magic numbers 1, 2, 3, and 6 by halving them and doubling them, and nudging them, but it just wrecks the animation.

Does anyone know what the magic numbers mean?
Why is everything being divided by 2.75?  Why not 2, why not 3?
Why is everything being multiplied by 7.5625?  Why not 8, why not 6?

If someone could explain, or just enlighten me on how to take out the first bounce, I'd be eternally grateful.